# Swift - converting string to date returning one day prior to correct date

Tags: swift, xcode, date, dateformatter

I'm trying to convert a date string to a Date in Swift. My date string is returning as:

"28/05/2020"

I have this method:

```
    private func getDate(date: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: date)
}
```

But it is returning:

```
Optional(2020-05-27 23:00:00 +0000)
```

Why is this returning the 27th and not the 28th?

Comment: Note that the output is correct: 2020-05-27 23:00:00 +0000 (UTC) is midnight of 28/05/2020 in your time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Out , it will work

```
func convertStringintoDate(dateStr:String, dateFormat format:String) -> Date{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "GMT")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    if let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr){
        return startDate as Date
    }
    return Date() as Date
}
```

Call this function like this :-

```
 print(convertStringintoDate(dateStr: "28/05/2020", dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy"))
```